# Changing permalink changes stylesheet path?

Tags: permalinks, css

I have changed my permalink structure to `/%category%/%postname%/`.The links are working, but the problem is that my `style.css` is not working  in some of the posts which are inside the category.

Comment: Can you link me to the problem?

Comment: i found out the reason..when i changed the permalink,the url is like 'domainname/category/page' and now for style sheet the requested url  is like 'domain name/category/wp-content/twentyten/style.css.'is this the problem with permalink?

Comment: how come the style sheet url change like this?

Comment: what's the code you're using for the stylesheet url? `<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>` or something else?

Answer (score 5):

At a guess I'd say you're linking to your stylesheet with a relative url like so:

```
<link href="wp-content/themes/my-theme/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

so when you end up anywhere other than the home page it's looking at the full URL plus the path indicated to your stylesheet.

Make sure your stylesheet URL begins with a slash if you're putting it in as static HTML eg:

```
<link href="/wp-content/themes/my-theme/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

*Even better* though is to use the built-in wordpress function for getting the stylesheet URL as Eileen has indicated in the comments. Use this syntax:

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" />
```

In order to include other CSS files look into the `wp_enqueue_style()` function in the codex - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

Comment: np. Can you mark it as the answer to your problem? Keeps the site tidy and rewards me with reputation :)